# How to fix pyspark to elasticsearch corrupt record issue

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, kibana

So I'm trying to process data in Spark coming from a kafka stream then send it to elastic search so that I can visualize it in Kibana. However, when I see the data in Kibana, the data is showing up as a corrupt record instead of it being it's own field.

Here is the code to process and send the data to elasticsearch. The data coming into kafka are just the text data from twitter and I'm applying a couple of functions onto them.

```
def process(time, rdd):
  print("========= %s =========" % str(time))
  try:
    sqlContext = getSqlContextInstance(rdd.context)
    df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
    results = df.toJSON().map(lambda j: json.loads(j)).collect()
    send_elastic(results,"index1","document")
  except:
    pass

def main():
  createIndex("index1")
  sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreaming", master="local[2]")
  sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
  ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)
  kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'localhost:2181', 'spark-streaming', {'twitter':1})
  tweets = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1])).map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
  sentiments = tweets.map(lambda x: {'tweet': x['text'],'candidate': get_candidate(x['text']),'sentiment':sentiment(x['text'])})
  sentiments.foreachRDD(process)
  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
```

This is what the data is showing up as in Kibana. As you can see it is showing up as a corrupt record instead of my intention which is to have it be a text, sentiment and candidate field. I appreciate any and all help I can get, thanks.

[output in kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3kH1.png)

Answer (score 0):

This line `df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)` by default expects to have a single JSON object in single line.

Check this link as [reference](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-json.html)

Your json file must be having one document per row. For e.g. as below:

```
{ "tweet": "RT @humanidee: @john_arcadian @wikileaks @marcorubio Tweet between Bernie and Hilary", "candidate": "Bernie", "sentiment": "negative"}
{ "tweet": "RT @lissbrantley: Outside the Bernie rally in #Concord and @MSNBC is out here asking everyoneif they believe in capitalism and if not @Ber..", "candidate": "bernie", "sentiment": "neutral" }
```

Now if you want to process multi-line then you need to add the below code

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("multi.json")
mdf.show(false)
```

As an added note make sure that the JSON object is in proper format. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response and help. So I got it working, what I did what create a udf in the dataframe instead of having it all on one line.

Comment: @mourya I'm glad you found a solution. Feel free to upvote or accept the answer if you think this helped. I've mentioned accepting the answer as well because I see you are new to stackoverflow. If you accept the answer, if you think it is one, that way people who would be reading your question would know that this question has an effective solution and its useful. Welcome to sof!!